# React: Cannot ready property 'readContext' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-cache

react-cache is not working with Suspense.

My code

```
  import React, { Suspense } from "react";
  import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
  import { unstable_createResource as createResource } from "react-cache";

    const MarkdownCache = createResource(input => {
       return new Promise(resolve => resolve(input));
    });

    const App = () => {
        return (
           <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
               <Test />
           </Suspense>
        );
    }

    const Test = () => {
           const input = MarkdownCache.read("Test react cache");
           return input;
     }
```

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(, rootElement);

Versions I am using:

```
  react: 16.8.0-alpha.0
  react-dom: 16.8.0-alpha.0
  react-cache: 2.0.0-alpha.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround for this problem I found from the internet is...

If you just want to run the program in the development env, you can modify the code in 'react-cache/cjs/react-cache.development.js' by yourself:
old:

```
    var currentOwner = React.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentOwner;

    function readContext(Context, observedBits) {
        var dispatcher = currentOwner.currentDispatcher;
        if (dispatcher === null) {
        throw new Error('react-cache: read and preload may only be called from within a ' + "component's render. They are not supported in event handlers or " + 'lifecycle methods.');
       }
       return dispatcher.readContext(Context, observedBits);
     }
```

'currentOwner' is no use except in function readContext. so here is the new:

```
      var currentDispatcher =      React.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentDispatcher;

     function readContext(Context, observedBits) {
          var dispatcher = currentDispatcher.current;
          if (dispatcher === null) {
               throw new Error('react-cache: read and preload may only be called from within a ' + "component's render. They are not supported in event handlers or " + 'lifecycle methods.');
           }
          return dispatcher.readContext(Context, observedBits);
         }
```

And that work in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Current alpha of `react-cache@2.0.0-alpha.1` is not compatible with newly published `react@16.8.0-alpha.0` and `react-dom@16.8.0-alpha.0`.

Downgrade to `react@16.7.0-alpha.1` and `react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.1` till new compatible alpha version of `react-cache` is released.

Answer (score 2):

Modify/Replace the code in 'react-cache/cjs/react-cache.development.js'

**OLD -:**

```
var currentOwner = React.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentOwner;

function readContext(Context, observedBits) {
  var dispatcher = currentOwner.currentDispatcher;
  if (dispatcher === null) {
    throw new Error('react-cache: read and preload may only be called from within a ' + "component's render. They are not supported in event handlers or " + 'lifecycle methods.');
  }
  return dispatcher.readContext(Context, observedBits);
}
```

**NEW -:**

```
const ReactCurrentDispatcher =
  React.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED
    .ReactCurrentDispatcher;

function readContext(Context, observedBits) {
  const dispatcher = ReactCurrentDispatcher.current;
  if (dispatcher === null) {
    throw new Error(
      'react-cache: read and preload may only be called from within a ' +
        "component's render. They are not supported in event handlers or " +
        'lifecycle methods.',
    );
  }
  return dispatcher.readContext(Context, observedBits);
}
```